# disable assembler logo in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

there are options to disable compiler and linker logos in visual studio, but I can't find such option for assembler. is there a way to disable assembler logo?

it looks like this, and shows up on every build:

```
1>  Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 12.00.30723.0
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>   Assembling: match686.asm
1>   Assembling: inffas32.asm
1>  Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 12.00.30723.0
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard option is `/nologo` for Microsoft programs.  ML.exe implements it as well, as you can tell with the other option all Microsoft command line programs implement, the `/?` option to get help.

Comment: Oh men, how did I miss that ML is acctualy a command line program and all you need to do is type "program name /?" :) thanks so much!